# Android NDK is crystaX the way to go for wchar support?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I need advice about wchar on android.  Is crystax compilation supported for Android Marketplace?  Also does the WCHAR support now include comparison operators like wcscmp? I've got wchar* , const wchar* foo(const wchar* )  and wchar_t* [] everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

1. Yes, applications built with my NDK can be pushed to Android Market with no problems.
2. Yes, full set of standard C functions (except of wprintf as for now) to work with wchar is supported.